# How to enable Rich text editor for content types

Tags: entities, webforms, wysiwyg

I have installed Ckeditor module and configured it to work with advanced editing options. But couldn't get rich text editor. I even tried all options in content authoring I din't get any solution.

And I want to enable rich text editor for certain fields and webforms. Here my case is the rich text editor should be enabled only some fields not all the fields.

For example, if i have two text fields(text areas) like summary and body. Only the body field should be enabled with rich text format the other should show basic editor. Can I have a clear answer.

Comment: check this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hq5NwrIUVrg

Comment: Check out this: http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/mod_ckeditor.html

Comment: Check this [Installing CKEditor in Drupal 7](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/install-ckeditor-in-drupal-7/)

Comment: You can also check [3 Getting Your CKEditor Setup In Drupal 7](http://drupal7tutorials.com/tutorial/3-getting-your-ckeditor-setup-drupal-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go and write in drush command prompt-

   sudo drush en ckeditor -y
2. Use full HTML format while editing the node as shown in attached
   screenshot.

[image]